# Display Loading Image on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to have my activity indicator start animating as soon as the user clicks on a row in my tableview. My problem is that the activity indicator doesn't start animating right away. My understanding is that the UI is not updated and the activity indicator does not start animating until all of the operations in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath are completed.

How can I edit this block of code to animate the activity indicator right when the user clicks a row?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath
{

// Activity Indicator
[activityIndicator startAnimating];

NSDictionary *item;

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    item = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[filteredListItems 
    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
} else {
    item = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[listItems  
    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

//Push to New View Controller
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
profileViewController.newsArticle = item;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I have been fiddling with these bits of code, but don't know how to tie it all together. Any help would be great! Thank you!

```
[self performSelector:@selector(pushDetailView:) withObject:tableView afterDelay:0.1];

- (void)pushDetailView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Push the detail view here
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the displaying of the loading image on a separate thread? This could solve your issue because when you tap the cell and perform everything on the same thread ("segueing" and displaying the loading screen) the view will not update until the segue is done.

Comment: Hi Filip, I am not sure how to go about doing that. Do you have an example? Thank you!

Comment: What is your loading image? Is it an image you're downloading, or one you have in your bundle? Is the image view in one cell, or many?

Comment: Hi rdelmar, I know what the problem is. Its that the image is getting called in didselectrowatindexpath. I understand that the UI will get updated only when all the operations over. Thus its waiting a few seconds before displaying. I will be opening a new question.

Comment: I updated my code above to shoe my progress. Any guidance would be great! Thank you!

Comment: @Filip I'm pretty sure you can't work with the view on any thread beyond the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might not be a solution, but a possible workaround.

Move your "rest of the code here" to a separate method and call it with a delay using

```
self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:
```

I hope this will let your loading image view to appear before performing the selector.

**update:**

I would suggest you to something like below, after determining item pass it to the delayed method and leave the rest to it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
                                                                *)indexPath
{

// Activity Indicator
[activityIndicator startAnimating];

NSDictionary *item;
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    item = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[filteredListItems
                                                     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
} else {
    item = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[listItems
                                                     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

[self performSelector:@selector(pushDetailView:) withObject:item afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void)pushDetailView:(id)item {
// Push the detail view here


//Push to New View Controller
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]
                                              initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
profileViewController.newsArticle = item;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi Galaxy, I think I am moving in the right direction here. Please see my updated code. Any help would be great! Thank you!